# Merging two pandas dataframes on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
>>> df1
[Output]: col1   col2   col3   col4
           a     abc     10    str1
           b     abc     20    str2
           c     def     20    str2
           d     abc     30    str2

>>> df2
[Output]: col1   col2   col3   col5   col6
           d     abc     30    str6    47
           b     abc     20    str5    66
           c     def     20    str7    53
           a     abc     10    str5    21
```

Below is what I want to generate:

```
>>> df_merged
[Output]: col1   col2   col5
           a     abc    str5
           b     abc    str5 
           c     def    str7
           d     abc    str6
```

I don't want to generate more than 4 rows and that is usually what happens when I try to merge the dataframes. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: I dont quite understand what your trying to merge on. Just col1? col1 and 2? In your example it actually wouldn't matter.

Comment: Why `merge`? I see only a sorted `df2` with subsetted columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.merge` by subselecting the correct columns and using `col1` & `col2` as key columns:

```
df1[['col1', 'col2']].merge(df2[['col1', 'col2', 'col5']], on=['col1', 'col2'])

  col1 col2  col5
0    a  abc  str5
1    b  abc  str5
2    c  def  str7
3    d  abc  str6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()
df_merged['col1'] = df1['col1'][0:3]
df_merged['col2'] = df1['col2'][0:3]
df_merged['col5'] = df2['col5'][0:3]
```

Does that help with what you're looking for?

Comment: My actual dataframes are much bigger that's why I wanted to use `
merge()`